# The Argument type 'object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string'......quiz app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This error gets removed if I add  ?.toString() ?? '' but it's not working then. Its in line
"questions[questionindex]['questionText']".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'answer.dart';
import 'question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final questionindex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(
      {required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questions,
      required this.questionindex});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
           Question(
        questions[questionindex]['questionText']
      ), 
      ...((questions[questionindex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
              .map((answer) => Answer(
                    () => answerQuestion(answer[
                        'score']), 
                    answer['text'].toString(),
                  )) 
          ).toList() 
    ]);
  }
}
```

It's a quiz app that I am trying to build
Question widget code is this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        //we use container around the text instead of directly using text to get everything in center not just buttons
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10), //spacing around the container
        child: Text(
          questionText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because `questions[questionindex]['questionText']` is an object type and the widget `Question` requires a `String` type parameter.
So when you add `.toString()` method, it converts the object type variable to a string type variable.

Let's consider this code

```dart
List<Map<String, Object>> questions = [{'a': someObj1, 'b': someObj2}, {'c': someObj3, 'd': someObj4}];
```

Here questions is a list of maps, and assume the variable `someObj` is a object in your code.
When you write `questions[questionindex]['a']` then you are referring to `someObj1` or that object.

So you are not passing a string, instead you are passing an object to the `Question` widget.

You can change the `Question` widget so that it accepts an object or you have to pass the string in that object, if it has any `String` property

Comment: Hey I have added thanks for your response

Comment: Yeah @kavyabhargava , I have updated my answer, it should help.